Taking damage while dying in 3.5
So, new DM to 3.5 here.
Let's say one of my players is hit by an enemy while at 5hp, and takes 10 points of damage.
That player is now at -5hp and dying.
Now, what if they took a further 3 points of damage from say, an area attack? Would they now be at -8hp?
The reason behind this questions is purely out of preparedness, I don't plan on attacking my players while down most of the time, and just want to understand how the rule works.

Yeah, that's how it works. Just be mindful that your PC is likely in prone position (hence could potentially get Cover depending on the terrain) while dying, and would be dead if the HP reaches -10 or less.

It’s probably not worth mentioning in a basic answer like this, but for what it’s worth, there are a very few things that can extend that −10 to lower numbers. Highly overcosted and not worth using, sadly.

To that point, I recommend looking to what Pathfinder does (death occurs at negative HP equal to a creature's CON score). Pathfinder can be thought of as a refinement of 3.5e ruleset in many cases (but not all), and might be worth looking into for OP.

Meaning that a level 19 character on -1 HP is just as vulnerable as a lvl 1 character on -1 HP? Absolutely love that, this is exactly what I needed!

Remember to have water close at hand and drown yourself, if you're at negative HP. That'll get you back up to 0.

@DiegoElias well, almost - at the very least, that level 19 character will probably have better armor, and quite a few enchanted items. Those might still turn away stray shots and attacks by opportunistic rats that would be quite the threat to a level 1 character in basic leather armor. The level 19 character won't be able to dodge anything, but his better equipment and higher attributes may still help depending on what the actual threat is.
